# Multiply two complex number on GPU using OpenCL

Tags: c++, kernel, gpu, opencl, c99

I'm trying to write a OpenCL based code to calculate `exp()` of some complex numbers on GPU using the following kernel function:

```
#include <complex.h>

inline float complex exp(float complex z) {    
    return (exp(__real__(z)) * (cos(__imag__(z)) + sin(__imag__(z))*I ));
}

__kernel void
calculate(__global float * c)
{    
    int nIndex = get_global_id(0);
    float complex rays = 1.0f + 1.0f * I;
    float complex ans = exp(rays); 
    c[nIndex] = __real__(ans * ans);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
ASSERTION FAILED: I.hasStructRetAttr() == false
```

The `*` works well with other complex numbers but it produce error for multiplying `exp()` functions output. Also I use `+` and `-` operators with `exp()` functions output without any problem. Just I have problem with `*` and `/` operators.